# Is there a way to install remotely a Package in an Org?

Tags: managed-package, deployment, package, migration-tool, package-install

I'm wondering if there is a way to install a Package in an Org but remotely, not by logging me into the Org itself.

Let me give you an example. Let's suppose I have:

- Org A
- Org B
- Org C

and I want to install the same Package (not Ant code deployments) in those three Orgs in one bulk. Salesforce offers any tool to accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can install a package over the API, but you always must be authenticated to the org as a user with appropriate permissions (typically a System Administrator).

You can do API installs by generating and deploying `InstalledPackage` entities via the Metadata API, or by using the `PackageInstallRequest` Tooling API object.

There's no way to install a package without being authenticated to a specific org via the API. It's always a single operation per org, not a bulk operation.